# Importing key file "filename.pfx" was canceled.

Tags: signing, pfx

I downloaded a open source project and was trying to open it in VS 2010. It contained the .pfx file which gives me the above mentioned error while building the project.

I tried signing it using sn -i VS_KEY_GHSTGEDY8755075 but it asks me for the password.

How can I fix this error ?

Answer (score 47, accepted):

I experienced this issue in VS 2005 and the solution was as stated here: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/Vsexpressvcs/thread/c33d7f75-6893-4793-a407-3aa3d49c098c/

I am not familiar with VS 2010, but I imagine that this is the same issue and can be solved in similar fashion.

> Open the project properties -> signing
>
> Uncheck the following options:
>
> 1. Sign the clickonce manifests
> 2. Sign the assembly
>
> Save the project and try building the solution.

Comment: But where is project properties?

Comment: I mean, I found project properties by right clicking the project, but I am not sure if that's the properties you're talking about because I do not find the signing option.

Comment: In the Project Menu.

Comment: Check under the signing tab on the left pane.

Comment: Strange, it automatically checks itself after debugging.